# Select variables on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I am trying to select columns on multiple conditions: 1. I want to select specific columns but I also want to select variables with specific expressions in their name.
I tried this:

```
df.waste <- w0%>%
  select(council_name, Period, year | contains("households" | "Tonnage"))
```

So I am trying to select the columns "council_name", "Period", "year" AND all those which contain the expressions "household" OR "Tonnage" in their name.

I tried different things all similar to the one above but I'm not quite getting what I want.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `w0 %>% select(council_name, Period, year, contains(c("households", "Tonnage")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
w0%>%
  select(council_name, Period, year | contains(c("households", "Tonnage")))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  council_name Period year  householdsabc Tonnageabc
  <lgl>        <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>         <lgl>     
1 NA           NA     NA    NA            NA
```

---

*Data*

```
council_name <- NA
Period <- NA
year <- NA
householdsabc <- NA
Tonnageabc <- NA

w0 <- tibble(council_name, Period, year, householdsabc, Tonnageabc)
```

Comment: Perfect. Was so close and couldn't figure it haha. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Also as mentioned by @Darren you can replace `|` with `,`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `grep` in `base R`

```
w0[c(1, 2, grep("households|Tonnage", names(w0)))]
```